# I'm trying to insert an image into this code so that it shows up on the screen, but it's not working. Does anyone know how to do this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to insert a picture of pancakes into the below code so that it shows up above all of the pages. This is using javascript. How do I program this? None of the code I'm using is working :( I've tried adding it, but that doesn't work, and then trying to import a png from my laptop isn't working either

```jsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, TextInput, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const Recipe = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [word, setWord] = useState(" ");
  const [definition, setDefinition] = useState(" ");

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput placeholder="Ingredients" />
      <TextInput placeholder="1 1/2 cup flour" />
      <TextInput placeholder="3 1/2 teaspoons baking powder" />
      <TextInput placeholder="1 Tablespoon sugar" />
      <TextInput placeholder="pinch salt" />
      <TextInput placeholder="1 1/4 cup milk" />
      <TextInput placeholder="3 tablespoons butter" />
      <TextInput placeholder="1 egg" />
      <TextInput placeholder=" " />
      <TextInput placeholder="Directions:" />
      <TextInput placeholder=" " />
      <TextInput placeholder="Step 1" />
      <TextInput placeholder="Sift flour, baking powder, sugar, and salt together in a" />
      <TextInput placeholder="large bowl. Make a well in the center and add milk," />
      <TextInput placeholder="melted butter, and egg; mix until smooth." />
      <TextInput placeholder=" " />
      <TextInput placeholder="Step 2" />
      <TextInput placeholder="Heat a lightly oiled griddle or pan over medium-high heat." />
      <TextInput placeholder="Pour or scoop the batter onto the griddle, using" />
      <TextInput placeholder="approximately 1/4 cup for each pancake; cook until" />
      <TextInput placeholder="bubbles form and then flip. " />
      <TextInput placeholder=" " />
      <TextInput placeholder="Step 3" />
      <TextInput placeholder="Wait approximately 1 minute and serve with butter" />
      <TextInput placeholder="and warm maple syrup." />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 50,
    paddingBottom: 50,
  },
  itemName: {
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    height: 44,
  },
  itemDesc: {
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 25,
    height: 44,
  },
  border: {
    borderWidth: 4,
    borderColor: "blue",
  },
});

export default Recipe;
```

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/image

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways which can use to add an Image.

For example:

```
<Image source={{ uri: 'https://your URL }} style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }} />
```

Or, If you are importing a picture directly in your file. Use

```
source={Picture}
```